# Java Changing variables while instantiating an abstract class

Tags: java, class, abstract

I'm trying to make an abstract class, and while I'm instantiating a new object of that class, I'm trying to set a variable in the class.

```
abstract class TestClass { // Class I'm trying to change a variable in.
    public String testString;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass t = new TestClass() {
            public String testString = "TEST"; // Where I'm trying to set it
        };
        System.out.println(t.testString);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
null
```

I wan't it to output out "TEST".

Is there any way to make that happen using a method like the one I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an initializer block:

```
TestClass t = new TestClass() {
    { // initializer block
        testString = "TEST";
    }
};
```

Comment: seems like this is the answer. I can't mark you as the solution for a few minutes though. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public String testString = "test";
```

Creates a variable within the main function in Main which is separate from the one you want to change.

Try:

```
Super.testString = "test";
```

to change the value of the testString from the Super.